# Rostering at our workplace

Tags: manager

How do I draw to the managers attention, again, that he has given all the 'spares' shifts to the other casual person and not distributed them evenly? Each time he does the roster lately he seems to do this and when I say something, he's usually good and sorts it,  it I'm abit fed up with having to ask him.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure if spare shift is a good thing or not as I don't understand the word as such, but I would say anyway that if you're directly concerned by this, you then already have a fair point addressing it. If not, I would already stop wondering and let people that are address it with him.

If you're concerned, maybe he has good reasons to do so, therefore I would suggest not going to him to "report" a mistake, but simply question him on why he's doing so. He may have good reasons sometimes as simple as being reusing each time the same roster template, or colleagues of yours might have asked him to do so or said they don't mind, etc...

The important thing is to find the balance between how much this is bothering you and how much you're bothering him with it. At some point, he might get tired you always discuss his work as a manager. You probably don't want to irate a manager on a minor issue, and even more if you're not directly concerned.